# Error with construction, unable to find object when calling its method?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, constructor, g++, rvalue

I've created a few toy classes below. During compilation, it appears that the compiler has some problem with constructing the object, but throws the error when the object's method is called.

I've tried compiling using MSVC10 and gcc 4.9 and the respective error messages are:

- MSVC10:  error C2228: left '.get' must have class/struct/union
- g++ 4.9: error: request for member 'get' in 'test', which is of non-class type 'TestClass(DataContainer)'

What's the problem? Thanks!

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    template <class T>
    class Data
    {
    public:
        Data(T i) : d(i) 
        {}

        T get() const {
            return d;
        }

    protected:
        T d;
    };

    class DataContainer
    {
    public:
        DataContainer(const Data<int>& i) : d(i)
        {}

        const int get() const {
            return d.get();
        }

    protected:
        Data<int> d;
    };

    class TestClass
    {
    public:
        TestClass(const DataContainer& a) : d(a)
        {}

        int get() {
            return d.get();
        }

    protected:
        DataContainer d;
    };


    int main()
    {
        Data<int> a(100);
        TestClass test(DataContainer(a));
        std::cout << test.get() << std::endl; 
        return 0;
    }
```

This, however, compiles successfully.

```
    int main()
    {
        Data<int> a(100);
        DataContainer cont(a);
        TestClass test(cont);
        std::cout << test.get() << std::endl; 
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).  The compiler thinks you are declaring a function instead of an object.  This also works:

```
int main()
{
    Data<int> a(100);
    TestClass test = TestClass(DataContainer(a));
    std::cout << test.get() << std::endl; 
    return 0;
}
```